# Two simple questions on quotient rings.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

1) Suppose we have $R=\mathbb{R}[X]$ and $I=(x^2)$ then for $f(X) \in\mathbb{R}[X]$ we can write $f(X)=a+bX+X^2g(x)$ for some $g(X) \in\mathbb{R}[X]$. Why would this be true how I don't really see how we can say that I mean I guess it seems to make some sense but I'm not sure.

2) This is related to this image (It won't let me post it here unfortunately)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xgo7G.png

I have highlighted the steps I don't understand, why would that element have to be in $I$ and why would $X^3-2$ have to be a factor. I get that we want to find some $x \in I$ so that $x+I=0+I$ but I just can't see the justification here and why the steps work.

Could anyone explain?

Answer (score 1):

1) Given any $f(x)\in\mathbb{R}[x]$, by definition:
$$
f(x) = a_0 + a_1 x + a_2 x^2+ \cdots + a_{n} x^{n}
$$
for some $a_0, a_1, …, a_n\in\mathbb{R}$. Let $g(X)=a_2 + a_3 x + \cdots + a_{n} x^{n-2}$. Then
$$
f(x) = a_0 + a_1 x + x^2 g(x)
$$
So $f$ is in the desired form.

2) Let me explain first why  $(a-a')+(b-b')x+(c-c')x^2 \in I$. This is because $a+bx+cx^2 + I = a'+b'x+c'x^2 + I$ so $(a-a')+(b-b')x+(c-c')x^2 + I = I$. In particular, 
$$
(a-a')+(b-b')x+(c-c')x^2 = (a-a')+(b-b')x+(c-c')x^2 + \underbrace{0}_{\text{is in } I} \in I
$$
Once you know $(a-a')+(b-b')x+(c-c')x^2 \in I = \langle x^3-2\rangle$ which is the ideal generated by $x^3-2$, we get $(a-a')+(b-b')x+(c-c')x^2$ is a multiple of $x^3-2$. But $x^3-2$ has a bigger degree than $(a-a')+(b-b')x+(c-c')x^2$, so this can only happen if $(a-a')+(b-b')x+(c-c')x^2$ is the zero polynomial. In other words, $a=a'$, $b=b'$ and $c=c'$.